# C++0X Standard in support of Multi-threaded Programs

Tags: c++, c++11

C++ Standards committe is to publish the new standards for the language we all love so much in 2010 and the biggest support that is being provided, is for multi-threaded applications.... this sounds exciting .... any more inputs on this????

Comment: Read this: http://www.devx.com/SpecialReports/Article/38883

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a specific question regarding the new standards, I recommend doing some Wikipedia/Google reading.  Also, check out [these c++0x StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x).

Comment: Thank you Phoebus ... but the idea was to start a kind of a discussion wherein we all could share common knowledge at one place rather going through individual questions, which are more specific rather than generic towards the idea of C++0X standards..

Comment: I recommend at least marking this "community wiki" then, just realize it's possible it may be closed as "not a real question", as we stick pretty heavily to the Q-A format around here.

Answer (score 2):

For C++0x threads, check out http://www.stdthread.co.uk/. It's a complete implementation of the C++0x threading libraries, written by the guy who wrote a lot of the proposals that made it into the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Prasoon already linked to [my article on Devx.com](http://www.devx.com/SpecialReports/Article/38883), and Terry linked to my [implementation of the C++0x thread library](http://www.stdthread.co.uk).

You might also be interested in the series of posts on my blog about [multithreading in C++0x](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html), or in my book [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/book) where I go into greater detail about the details of multithreading with C++0x.